# Pin a tab in Cuba Platform app or protect from closing

Tags: cuba-platform

I want to show some statistics and links at a welcome/home tab. How can I pin a tab or protect from closing?

It is a good solution or should I use the mainwindow for the "dashboard"?

Comment: You want to have a home tab, that will always be open?

Comment: Yes. If it is a good solution vs. dashboard!?

Comment: It feels more natural to put this information on the main screen. Tabs are usually used to perform some entity operations, so they are closed when the work is done. As far as I know, since 6.0 release main window is customisable. Platform developers can help you with that.

Comment: A separate tab can be more suitable than mainwindow if you want to be able to look at the dashboard but keep some other screens open. Mainwindow is accessible only when all screens are closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the *preClose()* method of the [AbstractWindow](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.1/abstractWindow.html) class. If this method always returns false, then you window will never be closed.

```java
@Override
protected boolean preClose(String actionId) {
    return false;
}
```